# Write an IDE on top of IntelliJ Platform

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I want to write a custom IDE on top of IntelliJ Platform. Android Studio is an example. It was built based on IntelliJ Platform and was designed to support Android application development.

There are lots of git GUI out there. However, in Linux, I don't satisfy with any. That is my motivation to write a git IDE for Linux. IntelliJ IDEA already have a very good Git plugin. Using IntelliJ IDEA is a solution. But it is too heavy for opening entire project with different functionalities (Run, Debug, Refactor...) for just Git operations. Therefore, I want to make that plugin a complete IDE for only Git operation.

On IntelliJ Platform forum page, there are tutorials to write plugins. However, it doesn't have the guide for writing a complete IDE.

Are there any tutorials to help me get started?

Comment: Have you tried Google? The question is too broad to get a decent answer here. Maybe try to break down the question into specific chunks so the questions can easily be answered

Comment: Yes, I tried with Google.

Answer (score 0):

> IntelliJ platform is probably not the best choice for writing a general purpose RCP applications.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207769065-Developing-a-desktop-Business-Application-using-the-JetBrains-Platform

Git plugin has 65k lines of code, you are talking about gutting ~13M lines IDE (respectively 3M lines of pure Java source code).

Comment: Yeah. That is a huge amount of code. I should give up this.